# Prestashop 1.7 Override Search

Tags: prestashop-1.7

On the website i have a custom form with specifics arguments to do a research of products.
I would like the transform the original prestasop search to test if the specifics arguments are sent and if it's the case change the sql request.

What is the best way to do this ?

I tried to override SearchController and did a class
override/controllers/front/listing/SearchController.php
but can't modify the function getProductSearchQuery

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it "the Prestashop way" I'll suggest to build a module and use **hookProductSearchProvider** to route your arguments to a custom search.

Have a look at this [devdoc](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/faceted-search/) article.